# How can I check focused or not a input field in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I must show div when input in focus. How can I do it with vue js?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should use ***@focus*** event listener on your input. Then in your method you can change div's v-show | v-if attribute to true

```
<input type="text" @focus="showMyDiv">
```